# Nested action in a GenericAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I create a new nested route in GenericAPIView in django rest framework
for enable a API URL like 'report/tasks/export_excel'

#### Viewset

---

```
class TaskReportViewSet(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = TiempoOperacion.objects.all()
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    serializer_class = TiempoOperacionSerializer

    def get(self, request):
    """
    Some code for 'get' request ...
    """

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def export_excel(self, request):
        sheet = excel.pe.Sheet([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
        return excel.make_response(sheet, "csv")
```

#### Urls

---

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^report/tasks/', TaskReportViewSet.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

`@action` is only meant for `ViewSet`, `GenericViewSet`, `ModelViewSet`, all found in `rest_framework.viewsets`.

Comment: Thanks, I change generics.GenericAPIView for viewsets.GenericViewSet that contains the generic API Views.  Also I replace the "get" function for "list" that is the GET handler request in ViewSet